# Index (zero based) error when using verbatim string literal and appendformat

Tags: c#, stringbuilder

I'm trying to use string builder and append format to build some html.  How can I use the verbatim string literal and append format without getting the following error:
"Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list."

See this example:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(5469);<br />
sb.AppendFormat(@"<td width=""155"">{0}</td>", localVariable); // zero index error here <br />
return sb;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the type of `localVariable` an array?  If so the array is being interpreted as a params array instead of the first argument to a params array.  To fix this you need to explicitly cast it to `object` when calling `AppendFormat`

```
sb.AppendFormat(@"{0}", (object)localVariable);
```